# PHP - Transforming text content according to rules then persisting to database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a web application where my users can upload text documents and emails into what I call Streams. A stream is like a "stack", that holds all emails / documents.

My users can then add `fields` to the stream, and `field_rules`. This means, that every time a new document or email is added, the **text content** of the document/email, will be parsed according to the rules, and then the final parsing result is then stored in the database.

My current code works, to some degree, however, it feels a bit "hackish" as well as not very "Laravel like".

## My progress so far

Whenever a new document (or email) is added, it will be handled by a queue:

```
public function handle(DocumentHandlingFinished $event)
{
    $stream = Stream::find($event->document->stream_id);
    $ParsingRules = new ApplyParsingRules($stream, $event->document);

    $event->document->storeResults($ParsingRules->parse());

    return true;
}
```

OK, so in above I start off by getting the "Stream" that the document was uploaded to.

Then I instanciate the `ParsingRule` class, that will perform the various rules on the content of the document.

Finally, I save the parsed results to the database.

Below you can see my `ApplyParsingRule` class:

```
public function __construct(Stream $stream, Document $document)
{
    $this->data = $document;
    $this->content = $document->content;
    $this->stream = $stream;
    $this->fields = $this->stream->documentfields()->with('rules')->get();
}

//Iterate through each rule and parse through the content.
public function parse() : object
{
    $content = $this->content;
    $results = collect([]);
    foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
        foreach ($field->rules as $fieldrule) {

            $content = doSomething($content); //Minified for simplicity.
            $results[] = [
                'field_rule_id' => $fieldrule->id,
                'content' => $content
            ];

        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Now as you can see in my handle message, I call the `parse()` function and then saves the results:

```
$event->document->storeResults($ParsingRules->parse());
```

In my Document model, I have the `storeResults()` function:

`Document.php`

```
//Persist the parsed content to the database.
public function storeResults(object $results) : object
{
    //If the document was already parsed before, delete old records.
    if ($this->results->count() > 0) {
        $this->results()->delete($this->results);
    }

    //Use ->last() because we only want to insert the last parsed text result.
    return $this->results()->create($results->last());
}
```

So above flow works as long as the `$results` array contains information.

I was wondering if above code can be refactored / improved even further?

Another concern I have is, If the `$results` array from the `ApplyParsingRule` class is **empty**, then the `create()` method will fail.